# What happens to Kajia's insect tokens on death?

Tags: battlecon

On a 2v1 game where Kajia is the boss.  Do the insect counters stay on the dead character permanently?

The situation is when I advance back and pull to add a few counters to the opponent before killing them so they still have the counters on their discard pile.

I was thinking since they're dead and the discard pile does not shift, it's like the insect tokens will just fester.

That way if I use her `Burrowing` ability which adds +1 Power and +1 Priority for every insect counters, I still count the ones on the dead player.

Also in addition, the dead player can also be resurrected.  I think they should still be inflicted by the insect counters when they come back to life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me your interpretation is broadly correct.  I guess with a game like this its impossible to write a rules that account for every little situation.

If you read the 'first aid' section of rules they state :-

> When a player reaches zero life, he continues playing throughout the
>   recycle step of the current beat.

So any Insect counters gained the turn a player took damage that took them to Zero or less would go into the discard pile and any that were due to be returned would be.  Obviously the 'life loss' effect wouldn't apply as life loss effects can never take remaining health below 1.

The card for Kajia states :-

> When an opponent would cycle a discard pile with Insect Counters on it
>   back into his hand.....

and First aid states :-

> He does not play any future beats while at zero life.

As the player is not taking future beats the the discard pile is not cycled.  Similar to if a player use a 'finishing move' which also doesn't rotate the discard pile.  So if a player attacking Kajia in 2 v 1 mode if knocked out the tokens would still remain on the discard piles and count for the effect the 'Burrowing Style'   However what you said about that bonus being 'per insect counters' is wrong.  The card says :-

> This attack has +1 Power and +1 Priority for each discard pile with
>   insect counters on it.

So if 3 insect are on one player all on one there discard piles but not the other they only gain +1 Power and +1 Priority for the pile.  Not the number of insect counters on it.